# Cosmology in Hindu text

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, upanishads, cosmology

So I have a few questions. Number one what is the shape of the Earth as per Hindu text and what represents the current planet Earth? I know people have interpreted Bharatvarsha and Bharatkhanda to mean Earth, but they could just mean the world, and that too has different meanings. So also a glossary of words with their meaning based on the etymology of the words would help. Do Hindu texts provide a geo or helio-centric model? Also, could there be other ways to interpret text ie metaphorically? I am looking for non-puranic text. So, Vedas, Upanishads, and Ithihasas. As well as Nyaya's works. Please provide links to sources. Thanks!!

Comment: I have looked into other answers, but they're conflicting and not based on a set boundary of texts.